# Can anyone help me date this Puch Clubman Sport 12 Paceline?

Tags: identify-this-bike

I'm trying to figure out what year (or at least what decade) this old Puch was built. It came equipped with a 6-speed Shimano Positron RD and Uniglide cassette, and the serial number on the frame is 7547056.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Uniglide suggests its an 80s rear wheel, but it may not be original.

Comment: 1977-1983.... http://www.disraeligears.co.uk/Site/Shimano_derailleurs_-_Positron_indexing_insanity.html

Comment: @JoeK thanks a lot, I didn't know about the two-letter Shimano date codes. The derailleur on this bike says JH, which corresponds to August 1985. Thanks again!